# titanium appcelerator tunneling socket issue

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I am using titanium for cross platform development. when I run a project using selected mobile device, generates an error. the error is given below...

```
[ERROR] :  tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 100
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 100
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Abdul\.appcelerator\install\5.0.4\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\plugins\run.js:92:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
TRACE  | Sending exit signal to titanium process:  2932
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Kindly help ...

Thanks

Comment: May I suggest you create a JIRA ticket (jira.appcelerator.org) and include all relevant environment information (run "appc info" or "ti info")?